# When using ssh with priv/pub keys, how to connect to the destination using a user different from the origin machine?

Tags: ssh, authentication

I need to connect to hostB using user2 from hostA where I´m connected using user1.

I've run ssh-keygen for user1 on hostA and copied the public key generated in id_rsa.pub to the authorized_keys of user2 in hostB.

Then I tried to connect from hostA to hostB using the command:

```
   $user1@hostA> ssh user2@hostB
```

I still get a request for password:

```
   user2@hostB's password:
```

If I try to connect using the same user on both hosts, it works correctly:

```
   $user1@hostA> ssh user1@hostB
   Enter passphrase for key '/home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sshd will ignore your files if it doesn't like the permissions.  I was able to duplicate this behavior by setting "user2"s ~/.ssh directory world writable.

Comment: You were right, my problem were the permissions. When I set the permissions according with what is recommended in the OpenSSH FAQ item 3.14, it worked. http://www.openssh.org/faq.html#3.14

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell your ssh to use the private key of user2 instead of yours (user1):

`$user1@hostA> ssh -i /path/to/private_key_of_user2 user2@hostB`

Comment: notice that you can debug with ssh -vvv <rest of command> and you will see which keys are tested, @desasteralex solution should be ok as you force the key used, without informations several key are used, maybe not the one you want.

Comment: @regilero: Agree, but I came to the conclusion that lpacheco is using several keys already, see: "$user1@hostA> ssh user1@hostB". The public key of user1 already exists in the authorized_keys file on hostB, and so the user does on hostB.

Comment: If I owned both accounts, I could do that, but I own user2 and want to allow user1 to connect as user2 in a single machine. I understand that if I give user1 the private key of user2, he would be able to connect as user2 to any other machine that user2 has access, right?

Comment: @Ipacheco: Yes, if user1 got the private key of user2, he/she can connect to every machine on which the public key of user2 has been added to the authorized_keys file. Exception: user1 needs to know the username of user2 on the destinated machine (depends on into which users authorized_keys file you've placed the public key).

Answer (score 2):

You could also place the pub key of user1 in the `authorized_keys` file of user2 on hostB.

Comment: That's what I did, but it isn't working.